How to return results from COPY INTO from scripting block in Snowflake
How can I make a Snowflake / Snowpark scripting block return the resonse of a COPY INTO statment?
In our ELT pipeline I use Snowpark to copy data from an S3 stage into a table on a daily basis, like this:
sql_copy_into = f"""
    COPY INTO {target_table}
        FROM {stage_file_name_full_path}
        FILE_FORMAT = (
            TYPE = CSV
            COMPRESSION = 'AUTO'
            FIELD_DELIMITER = {field_delimiter}
        )
        ON_ERROR = CONTINUE;
"""

response = session.sql(sql_copy_into)
results = response.collect()

Now I want to store the results of the COPY INTO in a logging table, which is working well so far.
However, once I wrap the COPY INTO into a Snowflake scripting block:
sql_copy_into = f"""
    BEGIN

    TRUNCATE TABLE {target_table};

    COPY INTO {target_table}
        FROM {stage_file_name_full_path}
    FILE_FORMAT = (...)
    ON_ERROR = CONTINUE;

    END;
"""

response = session.sql(sql_copy_into)
results = response.collect()

Then I get the results as
[Row(anonymous block=None)]

It looks like the scripting block isn't returning anything.
How can I make the scripting block return the resonse of the COPY INTO statment?
I have read about the RETURN command, but I can't figure out how this can help me here.
The only option I see is to send two different SQL statements, once for the TRUNCATE and another one for the COPY INTO. Then I could avoid the BEGIN / END. But there has to be a better way.
Any hints are greatly appreciated!

It is possible to return output from Scripting Block using resultset:
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE tab;
    
    LET res RESULTSET := ( 
         COPY INTO {target_table}
         FROM {stage_file_name_full_path}
         FILE_FORMAT = (...)
    );

    RETURN TABLE(res);
END;

